# If $f$ belongs to L it does not follow that $f^{2}$ belongs to L.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

If $f$ belongs to L it does not follow that $f^{2}$ belongs to L.

Hello, I'm pretty sure that I need to find a counterexample to show this, I was thinking in a piecewise function but I haven't found a good one. If somebody could help me that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Does $L$ stand for Lebesgue integrable?

Comment: Yes, $L$ is the collection of integrable functions.

Comment: no $f^2$ Does not have to be integrable

Comment: $f^2(x)= x^{-1} $ on $[0,1] $